# Warning: left shift count >= width of type when reading bytestream into double variable in C++

Tags: c++, byte, bit-shift

I'm trying to read a bytestream into a double variable in C++.
So my code for this is the following:

```
double foo;
foo = bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[3] << 24) | (bytes[44] << 32) | (bytes[5] << 40) | (bytes[6] << 48) | (bytes[7] << 56);
```

As you can see I'm trying to read in 64 bits. And even though double isn't a fixed size, it should be 64 bits on nearly any machine. (`sizeof(double)` gives me 8 bytes as size)

But still I get this warning:

> Warning: left shift count >= width of type

Can I just ignore that warning - or can I somehow make the size of the double fixed (as I know there is no sizefixed floating point datatype in C/C++)?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Your bytes will be subject to the usual integer promotion rules, which are probably promoting to a 32 bit `int` type.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that should probably be `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: You may want `memcpy(&foo, bytes, 8);`

Comment: @MarkRansom: I wasn't sure I was giving sound advice, so I deleted my comment right after posting it (after you saw it, obviously), but now that you bring it up: do `|` and `<<` consider signed vs unsigned?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I'm not sure shifting is well defined for signed values, so I always try to keep to unsigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution for myself - but thanks to all the comments!

I tried `memcpy()` and that worked fine.

I solved it like this:

```
foo = bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[3] << 24) | ((uint64_t)bytes[44] << 32) | ((uint64_t)bytes[5] << 40) | ((uint64_t)bytes[6] << 48) | ((uint64_t)bytes[7] << 56);
```